# How to install android 4.0 ice cream sandwich version in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, sdk, installation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My office system already has some Android SDK versions 1.5, 1.6, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2 installed into Eclipse. These versions are working fine. Now I wish to install version 4.0 but I don't know? How can I install Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich into my Eclipse? I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

Also if you know how to install Android 4.0 under windows then please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You will be having an Icon in you Eclipse Bar.. That is SDK Manager.. Click on SDK Manager you will get below image :

Select on API level you want to download. Also ensure that any update is available for **ANDROID SDK TOOLS** and **ANDROID SDK PLATFORM TOOLS** , if so update it also..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, Luanch SDK Manager. It will show you Installed/Not Installed/ Updates available. Select whichever API level you want and hit Install Packages...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, what you need to do is to run android SDK manager. A new windows pop ups. It shows all the packages available. All you need to do is to update them.
You could do the samething by browsing to where your android-sdk. Go to tools folder and run android (./android). Again SDK manager pops up with all the available packages.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Download latest Version of Android SDK below link:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

It's contains android 4.0 ics sdk..!

(OR)

Open Android SDK Manager in eclipse it's shows android 4.0 sdk (or)API Level 14 shows not installed to you can download Package's for android 4.0 working..!

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind the proxy, go to **Tools -> Options** in Android SDK Manager and set the proxy setting.